# Creating a TIN model from a .txt file

Tags: qgis, mac, tin

I am having an issue with creating a TIN model.

My task is to create a map of Plymouth Sound for my UNI work. I have a .txt file with eastings, northings and elevation (Ill attach it). Due to covid ive had to move to QGIS from arc as running it on a Mac.

My issue is that when I import the data as a delimited text file which works I then want to create a polygon. My lecturer in arc just hits Create TIN and its done. Ive tried all sorts from the Delaunay Triangulation feature but this just gets stuck at 99%, to attempting to change the .txt file in QGIS.

It also doesn't need to be 3D so I believe I don't need to use GRASS.

Second image is the txt file imported with the track lines from our survey. This is as far as I could follow from ArcGIS lecture.

The txt file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried exporting the txt as shp and create the TIN after? Also a link to your data would be great, this way I can try it myself and get back to you.